# how to sum a column where certain values need first be multiplied by a constant based on text in another column

Tags: postgresql

I have following table:

```
side         amount   
=====================
buy     |     10
sell    |     17
sell    |     20
buy     |     5
sell    |     4
buy     |     30
```

Now I am trying to get a query where I sum amount, but the sell side need to be subtracted instead. How can I accomplish this in SQL?

So basically the following calculation
10 + -17 + -20 + 5 + -4 + 30 = 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a CASE expression:

```
select sum(case side when 'buy' then amount else -amount end)
from the_table;
```

The CASE expression returns the amount for "buy" and the negative amount for "sell"